# Emacs, Dired+. What mean one dot in dired mode?

Tags: emacs, dired

Window 7, Emacs 25.1, Dired+ mode.

Path: d:\temp\test\test2\test3\

In folder **test3** has 3 files: file1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt.

When I am in folder **test3** and click on two dots I'm up to one level (go to folder **test2**). OK.

But when I click on one dot (see picture) the cursor go to on file **file1.txt**.
[image]

1.Is this a correct behavior?

2.What mean one dot in dired mode?

Comment: FWIW, clicking `mouse-1` or `mouse-2` on `.` in Dired after loading Dired+ does not move the cursor to the first file name or anywhere else. What it does is `dired-mouse-find-file-other-window`, which means that it visits the same directory in another window. If you see the cursor movement you describe then that's probably caused by something else in your init file. What does `C-h k` tell you when you click `.`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say this is correct behavior. In directory listings the single dot usually represents the current directory. You can also see it if you open a command window and run `dir`.

And that the first *real file* gets selected when clicking the single dot entry might also be a 'default' behavior of the dired module.

Comment: I don't need one dot. Is is possible to remove it?

Comment: `(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook 'dired-omit-mode)` to omit `.`, `..`, and certain other files by default. See `C-h i g (dired-x) Omitting Variables` for more information (including how to customize what is omitted).