# How to hide one dot (current directory) in Dired mode

Tags: emacs, dired

Double dot (`..`) is useful since it allows navigating up one level. 
But I don't need the single dot... Is it possible to hide it?

[image]

Windows 7, Emacs 25.1, Dired+.

Comment: If you don't need the one dot, do you need the two dots?  Having the permissions show on the current folder is probably a helpful thing to refer to.  Why would you want or need to hide this information?

Comment: Becase when click on one dot the cursor go to first file in current dir. I don't need this.

Comment: I answered this in the comments to your original question http://stackoverflow.com/q/43605918

Comment: "*Because when I click on one dot the cursor goes to the first file name*": So **don't do that**, if you don't want to go to the first file name. I wonder what the real question (use case) is...

Comment: As I said in a comment to your other question, clicking `mouse-1` or `mouse-2` on `.` in Dired after loading Dired+ does not move the cursor to the first file name or anywhere else. What it does is `dired-mouse-find-file-other-window`, which means that it visits the same directory in another window. If you see the cursor movement you describe then that's probably caused by something else in your init file. What does `C-h k` tell you when you click `.`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Elaborating upon my comment from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43605918#comment74265589_43606275, you can use:

```el
(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook 'dired-omit-mode)
```

to omit `.` and `..` and certain other files by default.

See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(dired-x)Omitting Variables` for more information (including how to customize what is omitted).

In emacs 25.2 the default `dired-omit-files` regexp is `"^\\.?#\\|^\\.$\\|^\\.\\.$"` which we could alternatively set using `rx` like so:

```el
(setq dired-omit-files
      (rx (or (seq bol (? ".") "#")
              (seq bol "." eol)
              (seq bol ".." eol)
              )))
```

If you wanted to keep `..` visible, you could just remove or comment out the `(seq bol ".." eol)` line from that code.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind hiding the double period (since you can navigate to the parent folder by executing `dired-up-directory`, which is, by default, bound to `^` in Emacs 27.1), then you can include the  `-A` in `dired-listing-switches`. The code block shown below shows my configuration which includes the `-A` switch.

```
(setq dired-listing-switches "-l -A -h -v --group-directories-first")
```

From the `ls` documentation

```
       -A, --almost-all
              do not list implied . and ..
```